# How can I set cookies to an HTTP Request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, httprequest

I need to set cookies for an HTTP Request.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://example.org/",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
        game: "soccer",
        value: "2395",
        action: "newGame"
    },
    cookies: {
        "domain": ".example.org",
        "name": "SESSION",
        "path": "/",
        "value": "34645645765756757"
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. It sends whatever cookies are in `document.cookie` (assuming the URL is in the same domain).

Comment: If you want to send the cookies just send them as parameters or headers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to explicitly add cookies to your request, it will send the cookies you currently have.

If you are trying to link to another website you need to setup the HTTP cross domain access: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

and use

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

**You can also try to reset the Cookie header before your request**

```
$.ajax({
  //...
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3");
  },
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies will be sent and received for all same domain requests automatically.

If you need to send and receive cross domain cookies set `withCredentials`. You can not control what those cookies are

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
   //... other options
});
```